# Refactoring prepared statements queries code PHP MySAL

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Using prepared statements to query the database in PHP is making me repeat a lot of code.

For instance, if I want to fetch a particular user from the database in my users.php file, I do it like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=?";

// prepare sql statement
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// bind query parameters
$stmt->bind_param('i', $user_id);

// execute
$stmt->execute();

// get result object
$result = $stmt->get_result();

// fetch user from result as associative array
$user = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

To me, this is already a lot of code just to fetch a user. But no big deal, it is more secure so it is worth it.
The problem arises when I want to insert a post into the database in my post.php file. I do it like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts SET user_id=?, title=?, body=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('iss', $user_id, $title, $body);
$result = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

I am already seeing code repetition here. It means in my application if I want to query the database 100 times, I will have to repeat some lines of code such as the prepare(), bind_param(), execute() steps especially since the bind_param() parameters are always changing.

I have thought of refactoring this in one or two functions say in my database.php   file so that I can just call the function passing the query and the parameters and have that function do all the prepare() and bind_param() and execute() functions.

Is this possible? If so is it good practice?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Or you could use PDO, which has a much cleaner API to do things.

Comment: @Awa Melvine `$sql = "INSERT INTO posts SET user_id=?, title=?, body=?";` Is it a update query? please confirm it?

Comment: @EmptyBrain it is not an update query. It is an insert query. It is equivalent to `INSET INTO users VALUES(...) ...`. You can read more here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html